# Add "Keyboards" In App Settings

Tags: ios, keyboard, settings, ios-app-extension

How can you add the Keyboards option in the settings of an app?

Like such: [image]

I know the Siri & Search keys you must enter in your Info.plist, but I wasn't able to find how to directly add the keyboards option.

The purpose is to be able to turn on a custom keyboard from the apps settings rather than going through General > Keyboards > Add Keyboard.

If the answer is "You can not", how can you add a keyboard *from within the app's own settings*. There are several keyboard applications out there that have this feature, so unless it's a private deal with Apple I'm sure there is a way to do this.

Comment: It's not there if you just add [a Keyboard Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html)?

Comment: Not rn - prob need to add more to my plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply removing and adding the keyboard extension to an **already existing project** added the necessary elements to the `info.plist`. Not sure if this was a bug, software glitch on my end, or the alignment of the planets... all I know is that it is fixed now. Cheers!